# Problems with .vsp3d file from Civil 3D to 3D Max

Tags: import, 3d, export, autodesk

It maybe doesn't fit exactly to that forum but I really need help with the .vsp3d file.

When I want to export my project from Autodesk Civil 3D to 3D Max and open it in Civil View I only can open the Corridor Baseline and the Surface, however, everything else is not even shown in the Civil 3d Import Panel. I have created Assemblies in Civil 3D, but they doesn't want to be imported to Max.

**The question is, how can I get every item from civil to max with the .vsp3d file?**

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK found out how to fix it.

**I just made a clean deinstallation and installed it again**. Why it had that mistake I really don't know.